# How to manage States between ViewControllers in Swift?

Tags: swift, uiviewcontroller

I am struggling to address of what I believe to be a State issue between ViewControllers.

The navigation path is as follows;

1.User navigates from `VenueDetailsVC` to `DiscoverVC` and passes a `Venue` object as such:

```
func presentDiscoverVC(){

    guard let discoverVC = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "DiscoverVC") as? DiscoverVC else { return }

    discoverVC.venue = self.venue!
    discoverVC.showBackButton = true

    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self.presentDetail(discoverVC)
    }

}
```

2.User can then navigate from `DiscoverVC` to `PreferencesVC` and passes the same `Venue` object while clearing the local `Venue` object as such:

```
class DiscoverVC: UIViewController{

    var venue: Venue?{
        didSet{
            print("DiscoverVC venue name: \(venue?.name ?? "venue name")")
        }
    }

    @IBAction func preferencesBtnTapped(_ sender: Any) {

        guard let preferencesVC = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "PreferencesVC") as? PreferencesVC else { return }

        preferencesVC.selectedVenue = self.venue!

        presentDetail(preferencesVC)

    }

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {

            print("inside viewWillAppear venue: \(venue?.name ?? "venue name")")

    }


    override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {

        venue = nil

    }
}
```

3.User then navigates back to `DiscoverVC` from `PreferencesVC` passing the same `Venue` object

```
@IBAction func doneBtnTapped(_ sender: Any) {

    guard let discoverVC = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "DiscoverVC") as? DiscoverVC else { return }

    discoverVC.venue = self.selectedVenue!

    DataService.run.updateUserDiscoveryPreferences(forUID: Auth.auth().currentUser!.uid, discoverableBool: discoverable!, preferences: preferences) { (success) in

        self.dismissDetail()
    }

}
```

**PROBLEM: Is that the `Venue` object inside the `DiscoverVC` is nil even though it has been passed back from `PreferencesVC` on step three above??**

Here is the console output:

[image]

Comment: I think your problem is in `ViewWillDisappear` because you're setting it to nil and in the buttonAction you're setting the `venue` to the `selectedVenue` so you're basically saying that `selectedVenue` is `nil` and returning a `nil` value in step 3, I'm not sure but give it a try.

Comment: Thanks Yasser, the reason why I need to set it ‘nil’ is because the same  ‘DiscoverVC’ can be navigated to from the ‘TabBar’ and as such a ‘nil’ value will then force to look for the nearest ‘Venue’ instead of selecting it from the list of Venues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you are doing this:

```
@IBAction func doneBtnTapped(_ sender: Any) {

    guard let discoverVC = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "DiscoverVC") as? DiscoverVC else { return }

    discoverVC.venue = self.selectedVenue!
```

You are not setting the `venue` of the Discover VC that presented the Preferences VC. You are setting the `venue` of a *brand new* Discover VC.

You can use the delegate pattern to pass the `venue` back.

Create a `PreferencesVCDelegate`:

```
protocol PreferencesVCDelegate: class {
    func preferencesVC(_ vc: PreferencesVC, didDismissWithVenue venue: Venue)
}
```

Add a `delegate` property in `PreferencesVC`:

```
weak var delegate: PreferencesVCDelegate?
```

Replace the line that sets `venue` with a call to the delegate method:

```
@IBAction func doneBtnTapped(_ sender: Any) {

    guard let discoverVC = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "DiscoverVC") as? DiscoverVC else { return }

    delegate?.preferencesVC(self, didDismissWithVenue: self.venue)
```

When you present the `PreferencesVC`, set `self` as the delegate:

```
@IBAction func preferencesBtnTapped(_ sender: Any) {

    guard let preferencesVC = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "PreferencesVC") as? PreferencesVC else { return }

    preferencesVC.selectedVenue = self.venue!
    preferencesVC.delegate = self

    presentDetail(preferencesVC)

}
```

And conform `DiscoverVC` to `PreferencesVCDelegate`. This is where you set discover VC's `venue`

```
extension DiscoverVC: PreferencesVCDelegate {
    func preferencesVC(_ vc: PreferencesVC, didDismissWithVenue venue: Venue) {
        self.venue = venue
    }
}
```